# How do i create a container in wpbakery(visual composer) similar to bootstrap 3 container class?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, visual-composer

I'm pretty new to WordPress and its plugins and i'm used to writing my own code from scratch using bootstrap, so i'm trying to create a row with padding on both sides like you get in bootstrap by using `class ="container"` but i can't seem get how to do it using the wpbakery template builder.Can someone help?